# Android activity won't start

Tags: android, google-maps, onclick, android-activity

I have an app with a camera and map feature. It worked fine until i tried to implement it so that my location coordinates would show up with my map(latitude & longitude) but now when I click on the map button it just crashes! My app works in the way that when I log in I am presented with a welcome screen that has 3 buttons, a camera, map and logout button. The camera and logout buttons work fine but the map button just crashes the whole app since I iinserted the code for getting my coordinates into the LocationActivity class. Below is the relevant code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Welcome class**

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class Welcome extends Activity {

// Declare Variable
Button logoutButton;
Button cameraButton;
Button mapButton;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from welcome.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);  

    // Retrieve current user from Parse.com
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    // Convert currentUser into String
    String struser = currentUser.getUsername().toString();

    // Locate TextView in welcome.xml
    TextView txtuser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtuser);

    // Set the currentUser String into TextView
    txtuser.setText("You are logged in as " + struser);


    // Locate Buttons in welcome.xml
    logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout); 
    cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    mapButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.map);

    // Logout Button Click Listener
    logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        /** Called when the user clicks the Logout button */
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Logout current user
            ParseUser.logOut();
            finish();
     }

});        

    // Camera Button Click Listener
    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        /** Called when the user clicks the Camera button */

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Send user to Camera.class
            Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, Camera.class);
             startActivity(intent);

        }

     });

 // Map Button Click Listener
    mapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        /** Called when the user clicks the Get Location button */

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Send user to LocationActivity.class
            Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, LocationActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);

        }

  });

    }
  }
```

**LocationActivity class**

```
package com.example.myapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

LocationManager locationManager;
Geocoder geocoder;
TextView locationText;
MapView map;    
MapController mapController;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_map);

 // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    locationText = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lblLocationInfo);
    map = (MapView)this.findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(16);

    locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

    Location location =     locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
        this.onLocationChanged(location);   
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);
}

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged with location " + location.toString());
    // Displays lat, long, altitude and bearing
    String text = String.format("Lat:\t %f\nLong:\t %f\nAlt:\t %f\nBearing:\t %f", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude(), location.getBearing());
    this.locationText.setText(text);

    try {
        // This gets a list of addresses 
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10);
        for (Address address : addresses) {
            this.locationText.append("\n" + address.getAddressLine(0));
        }

        // Convert latitude and longitude into int that the GeoPoint constructor can understand
        int latitude = (int)(location.getLatitude() * 1000000);
        int longitude = (int)(location.getLongitude() * 1000000);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
        mapController.animateTo(point);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("LocateMe", "Could not get Geocoder data", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}{




    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**activity_display_map xml layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Waiting for location..."
android:id="@+id/lblLocationInfo">

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="0vFrUOhHMkbahT9zXqiz_DuNVWfPqlEyqcO8ftg">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment">

 </fragment>
 </com.google.android.maps.MapView>
 </TextView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:name="ParseApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:allowBackup="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.myapp.LoginSignupActivity" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.myapp.Welcome" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.Camera"
        android:label="@string/title_camera"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myapp.MainActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

     <activity android:name=".LocationActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
   </application>
 </manifest>
```

**strings xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="hello">myapp</string>
<string name="app_name">myapp</string>
<string name="Username">Username</string>
<string name="Password">Password</string>
<string name="LoginBtn">Login</string>
<string name="SignupBtn">Sign Up</string>
<string name="LogoutBtn">Log Out</string>
 <string name="CameraBtn">Camera</string>
 <string name="MapBtn">Create a Geofence</string>
<string name="Welcome">Welcome!</string>
```

Hello world!
   Tap the image to open the camera!!

```
  <string name="title_camera">My Message</string>
  <string name="title_map">My Message</string>

  </resources>
```

**Logcat UPDATED**

```
   04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.travsafe/com.example.travsafe.LocationActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.maps.MapView
 04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
 04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
 04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
 04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
 04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
  04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
  04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
  04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
  04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.maps.MapView
  04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):  at com.example.travsafe.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:44)
  04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5141)
  04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
  04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):  at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
  04-01 15:05:22.548: E/AndroidRuntime(18009):  ... 11 more
  04-01 15:05:24.547: I/Process(18009): Sending signal. PID: 18009 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you please post logcat?

Comment: As I can see there are two `LAUNCHER` activities in your Manifest

Comment: I have provided the logcat data above now!

Answer (score 1):

You have a static initializer block here:

```
{
    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Move that code to `onCreate()` - activity init is too early for such code as evidenced by the stacktrace:

```
04-01 14:05:42.713: E/AndroidRuntime(14793): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 14:05:42.713: E/AndroidRuntime(14793):    at android.app.Activity.initActionBar(Activity.java:1880)
04-01 14:05:42.713: E/AndroidRuntime(14793):    at android.app.Activity.getActionBar(Activity.java:1867)
04-01 14:05:42.713: E/AndroidRuntime(14793):    at  com.example.travsafe.LocationActivity.<init>(LocationActivity.java:131)
```

---

In your updated question the problem and its solution are visible in the exception message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"  android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: I've edited my code to do what you said but it didn't fix it. Can you just check I've put my static initializer block in the right place? Thanks

Comment: I've since provided my APIkey but it still crashes!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified APIkey in your Manifest.xml file..
`< meta-data 
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
android:value="your_API_KEY"/>`
Inside onCreate get your map instance like this..
`GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();` 
I hope it will help you :)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Waiting for location..."
android:id="@+id/lblLocationInfo">
<fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment">

 </fragment>

 </TextView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok so I've specified my APIkey in my manifest, provided metadata for my second activity in my manifest and moved my static initialiser block to my oncreate method in my LocationActivity class and still my app crashes. i.e no change!! I have provided more of the logcat as well!! Please help!!

Comment: Please remove following code (Its deprecated now) from your activity_display_map xml file... <com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="0vFrUOhHMkbahT9zXqiz_DuNVWfPqlEyqcO8ftg"> direct use  <fragment>